# How to display one lookup's values depends on another lookup's value?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to display a set of values in one lookup's control depends on another lookup's control in same list. so what I want to do for this situation? both look ups are pointing the same list...

its like choosing states from country list... and is there any simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPServices library if you are looking to do it on client side Javascript.

It has `SPCascadeDropdowns` function especially for this purpose.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is to create a cascaded dropdown list.

Take a look at the folling link:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619373/Cascading-drop-downs-with-Cross-site-Lookup-for-Sh

You will need to adapt it a little bit, but it should work fine.